# What is the syntax of IFEQ and RETURN Insert Instruction in BCEL?

Tags: java, bytecode, bcel

Given the following method :

```
public static boolean check(String name){
    return true;        
}
```

I want to add an if instruction that `returns true` only if the name is equal to bcel, i.e.:

```
public static boolean check(String name){
   if(name.equals("bcel")) 
      return true;  

      return false;         
}
```

I know that I should be using `IFEQ`, `IRETURN` and `ICONST_0`.. but I don't know the exact syntax.

Here is a portion of the method I am trying to finalize:

```
for (h=il.getStart(); h!=il.getEnd();h=h.getNext()) // il: InstructionList,  h: InstructionHandle
{
    Instruction inst = h.getInstruction();              
    il.insert(h,InstructionFactory.ICONST_0);
    il.insert(h,InstructionFactory.IRETURN);
    ..
    ..
    try{
        h=h.getNext();
    } 
    catch(Exception e){}}
```

Help please.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

BYTECODE of the first code:

```
iconst_1
ireturn
```

BYTECODE of the second code:

```
aload_0
ldc #2<bcel>
invokevirtual #3<java/lang/Sting/equals(<java/lang/object;)z>
ifeq 11 (+5)
iconst_1
ireturn
iconst_0
ireturn
```

Comment: You don't actually need the ifeq. You can just return the result of .equals directly.

Comment: Okay, but I just want to know how to insert those instructions please:
ldc #2<bcel>
invokevirtual #3<java/lang/Sting/equals(<java/lang/object;)z>
ifeq 11 (+5)